# Spring Boot Test @ConfigurationProperties не биндит в время тестов

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Всем добрый вечер.
У меня есть класс, который предназначен для биндинга с properties.
В классе помеченным `@Configuration` я делаю бин по типу:

```java
// В TargetConfiguration классе

@Bean("someBeanName")
@ConfigurationProperties("some.path")
public beanProperties() {
    return new BeanProperties();
}
```

Я хотел бы протестировать всю функционально этой конфигурации и для этого создаю класс тест по типу:

```java
@WebFluxTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TargetConfiguration.class})
class Test {...}
```

Проблема в том, что `BeanProperties` будет содержать нули, но если я сделаю какой-нибудь другой `OtherBeanProperties` и обозначу его через `@EnableConfigurationProperties` в `TargetConfiguration`, то он будет уже нормально заполнен, но для `BeanProperties` не могу так сделать, так как этот бин зависит от property в *test.properties*. И если я непоследственнов тесте через `@TestConfiguration` создам этот бин, то он тоже уже будет заполнен... 
Любая помощь привествуется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всему виной было `@DependsOn` цепопка до `BeanProperties` от класса, который наследует `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`. Такая цепочка заставляла `BeanProperties` инициализиоваться до класса, который обрабатывает биндинги. Обошел я это следующим способом:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("some.condition.property")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BeanPropertiesConfiguration.BeanPropertiesExtender.class)
public class BeanPropertiesConfiguration {


    @Validated
    @ConstructorBinding
    @Component("someBeanPropertiesName")
    @ConditionalOnBean(BeanPropertiesConfiguration.class)
    @ConfigurationProperties("some.condition.property.subpath")
    public static class BeanPropertiesExtender extends BeanProperties {

        public BeanPropertiesExtender(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 args)
        {
            super(arg1, arg2);
        }
    }

}
```

Теперь независимо от `@DependsOn` цепочек, `BeanProperties` нормально инициализируется при наличии определенных значений в `Environment` или не инициализируется и контекс не запускает, если парамерт не подходит.